# Determining Basis of any vector equation with only one formula

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I'm really struggling with finding the basis when it's just like $ax + by + cz = d$ :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that, since you have an over-determined system with two free variables, you can take $y$ and $z$ as any constants. Say $y = c_{1}$ and $z = c_{2}$

In that case, all elements of the subspace $V$, can be written as $(2c_{1} - 3c_{2}, c_{1}, c_{2})$.

This can be re-written as $(2c_{1}, c_{1}, 0) + (-3c_{2}, 0, c_{2})$

Taking $c_1$ and $c_2$, common, we have $c_{1}(2,1,0) + c_{2}(-3,0,1)$

So, the vectors $\lbrace (2,1,0),(-3,0,1) \rbrace$ are Linearly Independent and span $V$. Hence, this forms a basis for $V$.

If $u \in$ span$(\lbrace (2,1,0),(-3,0,1) \rbrace)$ $\implies$ $u = c_{1}(2,1,0) + c_{2}(-3,0,1) = (2c_{1} - 3c_{2}, c_{1}, c_{2})$

$x - 2y + 3z = 0 \implies u \in V$

span$(\lbrace (2,1,0),(-3,0,1) \rbrace) \subset V$

Conversely, if $v = [x$ $y$ $z]^T$ $\in V$, then $x - 2y + 3z = 0$, which is how we came here.

Comment: You should also show why the above vectors span $V$. For every $v\in span (u_1,u_2)$, we have $v\in V$ and hence $span(u_1,u_2)\subseteq V$ and similarly in the opposite direction.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yeah, how do I determin {v_B} in the fourth question? I'm sure  know what to do, but its like the methods giving me doubts

Comment: I'm not familiar with this nomenclature, do you want the coordinate vector for v with respect to the basis that we found?

Comment: If that is the case, find the specific values of $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ which will give you $[5,1,-1]^{T}$. It will turn out to be $c_{1} = 1$ and $c_{2} = -1$. To verify, show the product [B]X, where columns of [B] are the two basis vectors and X is $[1 -1]^{T}$.